# Setting up Python Flask app with admin section

Tags: python, flask

I've built a few small Flask apps before that were read only and I really enjoyed the process. now I'm adding an admin section to a Flask app and I'm looking for some guidance.

Current directory structure looks like this:

```
├── Makefile
├── Procfile
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── img
│   └── js
└── templates
    ├── about.html
    ├── base.html
    ├── contact.html
    └── index.html
```

My app.py file looks like this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


# MAIN APPLICATION
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/work/<gallery>/')
def index(gallery='home'):
    return render_template('index.html', gallery=gallery)


@app.route('/views/<view>/')
def view(view):
    return render_template(view + '.html')


@app.route('/data/<gallery>/<size>/')
def data(gallery='home', size='md'):
    data = '[\
        {"image": "/static/img/photos/md/img_1.jpg","color": "white"},\
        {"image": "/static/img/photos/md/img_2.jpg","color": "white"},\
        {"image": "/static/img/photos/md/img_3.jpg","color": "black"}\
        ]'
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I've done some research and found the [Blueprints framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/) and [Flask-Admin](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin) which seem like they might work together. Does anyone have an alternate suggestion that might be more efficient or easier to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprints allow you to group functionality into isolated modules.

If you feel your service will be very small, there's no need to use blueprints - you can add routes to the Flask application, like you do in your example.

However, if application will get bigger, it is better to split it into smaller pieces by using blueprints. In your example, "work" is first possible blueprint, "views" is another, etc.

Flask-Admin allows you to build administrative interface a-la Django admin. It does not matter how you're structuring rest of your application - you add Flask-Admin and it just works.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Front and back end will probably have less than 10 routes all total. Do you think I should have a separate app.py in a "real" admin folder, or is it okay to map routes for the whole app at one time in the root level app.py file?

Comment: No, you share app between your application and Flask-Admin.

If you have like 5 views and there's not much code in them, there's no need to move them to different python module. If you plan to grow, make app.py contain Flask application instance along with configuration and plugin initialization and put your views in separate views.py. Just don't forget to import views module for decorators to work.